# How can I change one prefab without changing all prefabs?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this code that will spawn in a lot of prefabs. It then edits the prefabs. The problem is that every time it changes a prefab it will reset and move all the other ones.
Can you please explain this and maybe find a solution.

Here's the code:

```
void createAtom (int number, string symbol, string name, int x, int y) {
    Transform newatom = Instantiate (P_atom) as Transform;

    newatom.parent = this.transform;

    newatom.name = symbol;
    newatom.localScale = new Vector3 (0.35F, 0.35F, 1F);

    int posx = numbersx[x-1];
    int posy = numbersy[y-1];

    newatom.localPosition = new Vector3 ((posx * 2.1F) + (posx < 0 ? 1F : -1F), posy * 2.1F, -1F);//.GetChild (1);

    Debug.Log (number + symbol + name + x + y);
    TextMesh[] child = GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh> ();
    child[0].text = symbol;
    child[1].text = number + "";
    child[2].text = "x0";
}
```

Comment: It looks like newatom should be positioned correctly each time, but the TextMesh children that are being populated are always the same three - the ones attached to "this" object, not the newAtom just created. That means the previous symbol, number, and "x0" assigned just get overwritten. Is that consistent with what you're seeing? If not, can you attach screenshots of the hierarchy view and the rendered output? (ideally with an "expected" version too, so there's no ambiguity)

Comment: This is how it looks
http://gyazo.com/033b7c9300ec453c989c10e159e575db
There is supposed to be different symbols and numbers

Comment: BTW the position isn't important

Comment: I'm guessing ("H", "1", "x0") are the fields on your default P_atom prefab, and ("Be", "4", "x0") is the first one you create? That's consistent with what I wrote above.

Try changing child = GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh>() to child = newatom.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh>(); if that solves it we'll know what the issue was.

Comment: Well that was a dumb mistake by me. Woops.
Can you please write an answer so i can mark it as solved and you will get your well earned points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextMesh[] child = GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh> ();
```

This line (and the three after it) is always getting the first three TextMeshes in the parent object's child hierarchy - not the hierarchy of the newatom you've just created.

That means that each time you create a new atom, you're overwriting the labels on the first atom you created, leaving the rest with their default values.

Instead, you probably want:

```
TextMesh[] child = newatom.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMesh> ();
```